# Add GROUP BY to django query

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

I have the following query:

```
titles = Title.objects.all()
```

I need to get `DISTINCT ('title')` for this query under certain circumstances. Django does not allow `distinct('title')` while using a MySQL backend.

Essentially, what I want to do is something like:

```
titles = titles.extra('GROUP BY title')
```

How would I do this correctly?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `[annotate][1]` to group by

```
titles = titles.annotate(Count("title")).order_by()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `.distinct()` method?

```
titles = Title.objects.values('title','other_columns_you_care_about_and_not_distinct').distinct()
```

If you do a `.distinct()` on a `.all()` you will return as many rows as you started with, provided of course that your id column is unique. So, you only pull back the columns you need in the `.values()`.